# Why does this SQL query in DerbyDB not produce results in code?

Tags: java, sql, derby

Okay for some reason this is baffling me. I have several tables in the embedded Derby DB, so I was testing a SELECT queries (each table has about 5 rows worth of data):

```
// Doesn't produce and results in the application
Statement st = DataSource.getDbConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LOGS");

// Does produce results
Statement st = DataSource.getDbConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM STATIONS");
```

The LOGS schema:

- MY_PLACE [INTEGER Nullable FK]
- LOCATION [INTEGER Nullable FK]
- DESCRIPTION [VARCHAR(1000)]
- DATEON [TIMESTAMP]
- MODE [VARCHAR(10)]
- FREQ [DOUBLE]
- ID [INTEGER PK]

Do you see anything that I am missing? When I run the same query in Eclipse's Database Development perspective, both queries produce results.

Comment: can you put the full code? are you printing the results? or just stepping with the debugger?

Comment: That's a lot of code. Is there something specific you are looking for? `rs.next()` produce false for the LOGS query

Comment: Since you are getting a new connection, did you remember to commit your changes?

Comment: New data is not being inserted or updated. It's already there. What should I be committing? This is simply a select query.

Comment: Is the logs table in the same database as the stations table? If not then you'll need to configure another datasource for it.

Comment: @whistling_marmot they are two different table schemas.

Comment: A **schema** is different than a **table**. At least it is in Derby: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefschemaname.html